# Can't open browser from a terminal in Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, browser

I've logged into Linux machine.
I issued the following commands to open a browser on the Linux server.

Still, I am unsuccessful.

```
07:53 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ nautilus .
-bash: nautilus: command not found
07:53 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ nautilus
-bash: nautilus: command not found
07:53 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ xdg-open http://google.com/
-bash: xdg-open: command not found
07:53 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ xdg -open http://google.com/
-bash: xdg: command not found
07:53 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ lynx
-bash: lynx: command not found
07:55 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ xdg-open http://stackoverflow.com
-bash: xdg-open: command not found
07:56 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$
07:56 AM tomcat@wb-ser1$ firefox
-bash: firefox: command not found
```

Comment: It looks like you are logged into a remote server, in which case it is likely that there is no GUI applications at all.

Comment: @user663724, what are you **really** trying to do? Why do you need the browser? What are you using to log into the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you are on a Linux machine with no web browser installed.

To see what things are "installed" on the machine, first check the search path of your shell:

```
echo $PATH
```

This should yield a list of dirs seperated by ':'.  Like so:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

next, you can list the files in each (probably a huge number, if it's a desktop install of linux):

```
ls /bin
ls /usr/bin
...
```

Comment: I dont know , but i guess the default firefox will be present know

Comment: By the looks of the error "firefox: command not found", it appears you don't have firefox installed.  See my updates for more info on what is 'installed'.

Comment: On echo $PATH , it displayed /usr/local/jdk1.6.0_20/bin/:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/tomcat/bin:.

Comment: it appears you are logged in as a webserver user on a webserver.  I'm guessing this has no browser installed.  Usually servers are as barebones as possible, as no one will ever need to run a browser from it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to download the HTML, you just need to run wget or curl command

```
wget http://stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Basically i want to start the tomcat server in linux and want to execute a web application .

Comment: Do you have a visual access, or only terminal ?!

Comment: i  have only terminal  .

Comment: Ok that's mean you can't run firefox and watching the GUI, you can only run wget and see the HTML output, the command is wger "URL"

Comment: ok maybe you can you lynx :)